# Is there any library like LOESS or ARIMA in Java/C# or Python?

Tags: time-series, software

I try to implement a time series data analysis project, but I have to do in Java, C# or Python, is there any good libary such like LOESS, ARIMA in R you can recommend?

Answer (score 7):

R is an open source project, so you can look at the file `src/library/stats/src/loessc.c` which implements the C-level computation behind `loess()`.  You should be able to use that for an extension module to the other languages you listed. Or, and this may be easier, you some of the existing ways to access R from Java, Python or C#.

Comment: (+1) There's some code available in the Scipy [Sandbox](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/browser/trunk/Lib/sandbox?rev=2844) which is based on Fortran code available on [Netlib](http://www.netlib.org/).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I bet it comes from the same original work.

Comment: Calling R from your preferred language seams the best solution in your case

Answer (score 2):

With respect to loess the [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython) project has a [lowess() function.](http://www.koders.com/python/fid5A91A606E15507B6823DEC7A059488A6624C4832.aspx?s=python)

As for ARIMA model fitting, [PyIMSL Studio](http://www.vni.com/campaigns/pyimslstudioeval/) contains a number of very useful time series analysis functions, including ones for [automatically fitting the best ARIMA model](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/documentation/PyIMSL/stat/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Csch8.9.9.html) and [identifying outliers](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/documentation/PyIMSL/stat/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Csch8.9.7.html) from it. These same functions are available in the other IMSL libraries if you choose to instead code in C, C#, Java, or Fortran.

Comment: PyIMSL is not open source, is it?

Comment: Correct. The PyIMSL algorithms are Python wrappers to the IMSL C Numerical Library (~500 math and stat functions), which is not open source. PyIMSL is free to use for non-commercial use though.

Answer (score 1):

Gretl is a very good and standard open source time series library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there aren't many options. Libraries for time series analysis free or otherwise are hard to come by.

If you are doing this for work you can have a look at [NAG](http://www.nag.com). It's commercial and not Java native. But you can use JNI with their C library.

They have a [time series chapter](http://www.nag.com/numeric/CL/nagdoc_cl09/xhtml/G13/g13conts.xml#g13) which does quite a bit.

On the free side there is [gretl](http://gretl.sourceforge.net) looks good, but I have no direct experience with it. If anyone does, I'd like to hear their opinions.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950004/java-library-to-do-time-series-analysis) on stackoverflow as well.